# Answer: (SQL) (TSQL) Determine Periods from Date Range

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, period

Using the `@ReportingEndingDate`, go back in time (`@NumberOfPeriods`)

1) Will take a starting and ending date range
2) Will do different'periods': Quarter, Month, or Year
3) Will do 'x' number of periods
4) Can start from the beginning date and go forward to the ending
   date or start from the ending date and go backward to the starting
   date. The former is obviously used regularly, however, the latter is
   used in cases where you want to pick an ending date and go backward
   'x' number of periods.

Some scenarios:
1)

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,@End DATETIME = '2014-08-15 23:59:59'
        ,@Period TINYINT = 1 -- 1 = Quarter, 2 = Month, 3 = Year
        ,@NumerOfPeriods SMALLINT = 24
        ,@StartingDateIsOrigniationDate BIT = 1

    SELECT * FROM udf_SplitDateRangeIntoPeriods(@Start, @End, @Period, @NumerOfPeriods, @StartingDateIsOrigniationDate)
```

1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM    3/31/2013 11:59:59 PM
4/1/2013 12:00:00 AM    6/30/2013 11:59:59 PM
7/1/2013 12:00:00 AM    9/30/2013 11:59:59 PM
10/1/2013 12:00:00 AM   12/31/2013 11:59:59 PM
1/1/2014 12:00:00 AM    3/31/2014 11:59:59 PM
4/1/2014 12:00:00 AM    6/30/2014 11:59:59 PM 
-- no more as last would be partial period

2)

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,@End DATETIME = '2014-08-15 23:59:59'
        ,@Period TINYINT = 1 -- 1 = Quarter, 2 = Month, 3 = Year
        ,@NumerOfPeriods SMALLINT = 24
        ,@StartingDateIsOrigniationDate BIT = 0
SELECT * FROM udf_SplitDateRangeIntoPeriods(@Start, @End, @Period, @NumerOfPeriods, @StartingDateIsOrigniationDate)
```

6/1/2014 12:00:00 AM    8/15/2014 11:59:59 PM -- partial period
3/1/2014 12:00:00 AM    5/31/2014 11:59:59 PM
12/1/2013 12:00:00 AM   2/28/2014 11:59:59 PM
9/1/2013 12:00:00 AM    11/30/2013 11:59:59 PM
6/1/2013 12:00:00 AM    8/31/2013 11:59:59 PM
3/1/2013 12:00:00 AM    5/31/2013 11:59:59 PM

```
/*
-- =============================================
   Author:          Daniel Kram
   Create date:   September 2014
   Description:   Returns a table with a date range
   Modifications:

   Example:

-- =============================================

*/

IF EXISTS (SELECT name
           FROM
             sysobjects
           WHERE
             name = 'udf_SplitDateRangeIntoPeriods'
             AND type = 'TF'
          )
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.udf_SplitDateRangeIntoPeriods;
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_SplitDateRangeIntoPeriods
(
  @StartingDate DATETIME,
  @EndingDate   DATETIME,
  @PeriodType TINYINT = 0,            -- 0 = use date-range only, 1 = quarter, 2 = month, 3 = year
  @NumberOfPeriods SMALLINT = NULL,
  @StartingDateIsFocus BIT = 1        -- 1 = Starting date is the origination point, 0 = ending date is the orignation point
)
RETURNS @DateResults TABLE 
  (FromDate DATETIME
  ,ToDate DATETIME
  ,MyRowNumber INT)
  AS BEGIN

    IF (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL) OR (@NumberOfPeriods = 0)
      SET @NumberOfPeriods = 99;

    IF (@PeriodType = 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT @StartingDate, @EndingDate, 1
    END
    -- Quarters, working backwards from ending date
    ELSE IF (@PeriodType = 1)
    BEGIN
      IF (@StartingDateIsFocus = 1)
      BEGIN
        WITH Quarters AS
        (
            SELECT @StartingDate AS 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartingDate)+3,0)) as 'ToDate'
              ,1 AS MyRowNumber
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST(DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(ToDate)) AS DATETIME) AS 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(dd,1,CAST(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,3,ToDate)) AS DATETIME))) as 'ToDate'
              ,MyRowNumber + 1 AS MyRowNumber
            FROM Quarters
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
        ) INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT * FROM Quarters
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
      END
      ELSE IF (@StartingDateIsFocus = 0)
      BEGIN
        WITH Quarters AS
        (
            SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,-2,DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, @EndingDate)+1, @EndingDate))), 0) as 'FromDate'
              ,@EndingDate AS 'ToDate'
              ,1 AS MyRowNumber
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,-3,DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, FromDate)+1, FromDate))), 0) as 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, -3, ToDate))+1,0)) AS 'ToDate'
              ,MyRowNumber + 1 AS MyRowNumber
            FROM Quarters
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
        ) INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT * FROM Quarters 
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
      END
    END
    ELSE IF (@PeriodType = 2)
    BEGIN
      IF (@StartingDateIsFocus = 1)
      BEGIN
        WITH YearPeriod AS
        (
            SELECT @StartingDate AS 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartingDate)) as 'ToDate'
              ,1 AS MyRowNumber
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(ss,1,ToDate) as 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,ToDate)+2,0)) as 'ToDate'
              ,MyRowNumber + 1 AS MyRowNumber
            FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
        ) INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT * FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
      END
      ELSE IF (@StartingDateIsFocus = 0)
      BEGIN
        WITH YearPeriod AS
        (
            SELECT DATEADD(ss,1,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@EndingDate)) as 'FromDate'
              ,@EndingDate AS 'ToDate'
              ,1 AS MyRowNumber
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(ss,1,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,FromDate)) as 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,ToDate) as 'ToDate'
              ,MyRowNumber + 1 AS MyRowNumber
            FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
        ) INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT * FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
      END
    END
    ELSE IF (@PeriodType = 3)
    BEGIN
      IF (@StartingDateIsFocus = 1)
      BEGIN
        WITH YearPeriod AS
        (
            SELECT @StartingDate AS 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(YEAR,1,@StartingDate)) as 'ToDate'
              ,1 AS MyRowNumber
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(ss,1,ToDate) as 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(YEAR,1,ToDate) as 'ToDate'
              ,MyRowNumber + 1 AS MyRowNumber
            FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
        ) INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT * FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
      END
      ELSE IF (@StartingDateIsFocus = 0)
      BEGIN
        WITH YearPeriod AS
        (
            SELECT DATEADD(ss,1,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EndingDate)) as 'FromDate'
              ,@EndingDate AS 'ToDate'
              ,1 AS MyRowNumber
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(ss,1,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,FromDate)) as 'FromDate'
              ,DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,ToDate)) as 'ToDate'
              ,MyRowNumber + 1 AS MyRowNumber
            FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
        ) INSERT INTO @DateResults (FromDate, ToDate, MyRowNumber) SELECT * FROM YearPeriod
            WHERE (     (MyRowNumber <= @NumberOfPeriods)
                     OR (@NumberOfPeriods IS NULL)
                  )
            AND FromDate >= @StartingDate
            AND ToDate <= @EndingDate
            AND MyRowNumber < 99
      END
    END
    RETURN
  END
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Could you clarify your question please. Is the output not what you expected and if so, what is the problem? What is it you want to accomplish?